# Connecting to University VPN (pptp) Linux Mint 18

Tags: vpn, pptp

I recently got a new Thinkpad that I loaded Linux Mint 18 (Rosa) onto. My School, Sacred Heart University, uses a VPN under pptp according to the tech desk. I say this because trying to connect regularly through wifi does not seem to work leading me to believe I need to manually connect to the VPN with my u-name and password. However I am having some difficulty connecting in that it will either never initiate or never complete. Is there some kind of package I am missing alongside the default pptp I see under VPN connections? If not, what am I missing that isn't allowing me to connect. I would post the errors if there were any to find, however I usually cannot get it to even initiate a connect, let alone attempt to connect. I have been searching around on google but can't seem to find any definitive information, I am hoping you guys can point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is really too broad for people to be able to answer here without just guessing.  Nobody here knows how that system is set up (or yours, for that matter).  As thesoundman20 suggests, your best resource will be the school's tech support.

Comment: From user [thesoundman20](http://superuser.com/users/639050/thesoundman20): contact their HelpDesk for specific help. Copied this from their website: You can reach them by calling 1-866-365-7575 for anywhere in the US except for the 203 area where you have to dial 203-365-7575. While on campus just dial the extension 7575.